# TeXworks can't compile any .tex document

Tags: compiling, texworks

I've just installed TeXworks on new computer (with ubuntu 10.4). It seems all required texlive packages are installed, in any case I can compile .tex documents using terminal. But in TeXworks while trying to run pdfLaTeX appears:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Szarfi.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \documentclass
                  {book}
?
```

Preamble is:

```
%& --translate-file=utf-8
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document} 

here goes the text

\end{document}
```

I've uninstalled and installed once again TeXworks, the problem persist. I had before more general problem with the system, I thought I've resolved it with help of askubuntu, the thread is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28195/untrusted-packages-could-compromise-your-systems-security-appears-while-tryin, I don't know if there is any connection between those problems.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Did you select `pdfLaTeX` next to the compilation button? I think the standard is `pdfTeX`, which won't compile LaTeX documents.

Comment: The default was changed a while ago, but it depends on which version you have. @Caramdir: Please make your comment an answer.

Comment: @Joseph: Ubuntu usually has pretty outdated TeX packages (and 10.4 is nearly a year old).

Comment: @Caramdir: As building your own TeXworks is easy on Ubuntu, it's hard to be sure if people are using one from a repository or making their own version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you select `pdfLaTeX` next to the compilation button? The default in the TeXworks version in Ubuntu 10.04 is `pdfTeX`, which won't compile LaTeX documents.

Comment: in effect, this is the problem. I thought having changed it (`edit -> preferences -> typesetting -> pdfLaTeX`), but I haven't notice that it doesn't "remember" my choice... Is there any way to change it for `pdfLaTeX`?

Comment: @maria `edit -> preferences -> typesetting -> Default: pdfLaTeX` works for me.

Comment: @maria: You'll need to restart TeXworks to get the change of preferences to apply to existing files.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked on my Linux MINT.

Open the terminal and install a LaTeX compiler (abntex)

```
~$ sudo apt-get install abntex
```

Then I installed TexMaker and it worked fine.